# Подсчет fps в игровом цикле

Tags: c, разработка-игр

Как в таком вот *game loop* подсчитать *fps* и поместить в переменную?

```
#include <sys/time.h>

#define TICKS_PER_SECOND 25
#define SKIP_TICKS (1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND)
#define MAX_FRAMESKIP 5

double getTimeInMs() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double) (tv.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv.tv_usec) / 1000;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    unsigned long int next_game_tick = getTimeInMs();
    int loops;
    float interpolation;

    while (1) {

       loops = 0;
        while (getTimeInMs() > next_game_tick && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
            update_game();

            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
        }

        interpolation = (float)( getTimeInMs() + SKIP_TICKS - next_game_tick ) / (float)( SKIP_TICKS );
        render_game( interpolation );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы знать, что такое fps?

Comment: Количество кадров в секунду.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю зачем нужен вызов `update_game` внутри вложенного цикла `while`. Какой смысл что-то обновлять, если эти изменения все равно не отображаются до самого конца цикла? А вообще не изобретайте велосипед. Есть давно уже проверенные способы организации игрового цикла. Почитайте например [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/184666/) (_Цикл игры_). Там правда используется Javascript, но суть от этого не меняется.

Comment: Где тут велосипед? Подобный игровой цикл много где используется Этот игровой цикл немного продвинутее того что в статье на которую вы дали ссылку, а именно данный цикл будет быстрее работать на слабом железе. Смысл в том что цикл(в котором происходит update_game() может не выполнятся например на слабом железе, тойсть обновление игры может быть редко за счет этого будет больше fps, а интерполяция сгладит редкое обновление игры.

Comment: _Смысл в том что цикл(в котором происходит update_game() может не выполнятся например на слабом железе_ T.e. как это может не выполняться? Он по-любому выполнится как минимум один раз. Но похоже вы не поняли мой вопрос: зачем вызывать функцию `update_game` на **каждой** итерации вложенного цикла?. Имхо более логично вызывать ее **после** цикла (перед `render_game`). Допустим `update_game` изменяет положение каких-то объектов в игре. Какой смысл вызывать ее несколько раз перед `render_game`? ведь результаты всех предыдущих вызовов `update_game` все равно будут заменены последним вызовом.

Comment: @hindmost предположу, чтоб математические расчёты модели игры имели меньшую погрешность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все до неприличия просто. FPS это то сколько кадров вы нарисовали за секунду.

После каждого кадра увеличивайте счетчик кадров и проверяйте время, если прошло больше 1 сек, то делите число нарисованных кадров на прошедшее время (чуть больше секунды будет) и обнуляйте счетчик и время. Если хотите плавности - проверяйте раз в 2сек например.

Answer (score 0):

Опишу алгоритм словами и псевдокодом:
Имеем следующие переменные: tstart - метка начала цикла подсчёта, count - нарастающий счётчик.

```
count++;
time = текущее время;
if ( count == 1 ) { tstart = time; }
else if( (time - tstart) >= 1sec ) { fps = (float)count / (float)(time - tstart); count=0; }
```